# If script is running more than once, how to deal with error variable already defined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with script as below. This script runs when user invokes the extension and it fills input field with some dummy value.

```
const firstNameSelector = ".input-first-name";

document.querySelector(firstNameSelector).value = "John";
```

It is working as expected. But if user is invoking the extension, more than once, it is failing with the error:

> **Identifier 'firstNameSelector' has already been declared.**

So, I changed the code as below:

```
const firstNameSelector = firstNameSelector || ".input-first-name";

document.querySelector(firstNameSelector).value = "John";
```

Now it is failing with this error:

> **Cannot access 'firstNameSelector' before initialization.**

How do I solve this situation? I feel like this is a simple problem but I am confused as how to solve this.

**EDIT**:
I could get around this by updating script as below but is there a way where I don't need to sacrifice variable declaration and keep code tidy and clean?

```
document.querySelector('.input-first-name').value = "John";
```

Comment: The example is very simplified version. I have more complex script and I cannot get rid of variables completely. Let me update question with these details.

Comment: You may want to look into singletons

Comment: Wrap your code in a function and run it.

Comment: The variable must be global?

Comment: @AlexSp3 No, it doesn't need to be global.

Comment: So what about my suggestion...?

Comment: @ChrisG I am actually trying your suggestion by wrapping all this in a IIFE and it seems to work. Going to try couple of scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly an scope problem. In js you cannot access to a variable before its declaration if the variable is declared in the same scope, that's why you got the error:

> Cannot access 'firstNameSelector' before initialization.

Since you don't need the variable `firstNameSelector` to be global, you can enclose the fragment of code that cause the error...

> Identifier 'firstNameSelector' has already been declared.

... in a separate scope, like this:

```js
console.log(typeof firstNameSelector)

{
  const firstNameSelector = ".input-first-name";

  document.querySelector(firstNameSelector).value = "John";
}
```

```html
<input class="input-first-name">
```

Here the curly brackets create a different scope so that the code will always be executed, and you can invoke multiple times the script without declaration errors.